# Change first value of group based on condition, pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Assume that I have the following dataset

```
table = [[datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 31), 1, 0.5, 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 30), 1, 0.5, 0.5],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 30), 1, 0.5, 0.5],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 31), 1, 2, 0.5],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 31), 2, 0.5, 1.5],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 30), 2, 0.5, 0.5],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 30), 2, 0.5, 0.5],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 31), 2, 2, 0.5]]

df = pd.DataFrame(table, columns=['Date', 'Id', 'Value', 'Old'])
```

Is there any way to change the *first* element of `Value` to the corresponding element of `Old` if the element of `Value` is smaller than the one in `Old`? It needs to be done by each group (based on `Id`). My new table would thus look like

```
        Date  Id  Value  Old
0 2015-03-31   1    1.0  1.0
1 2015-06-30   1    0.5  0.5
2 2015-09-30   1    0.5  0.5
3 2015-12-31   1    2.0  0.5
4 2015-03-31   2    1.5  1.5
5 2015-06-30   2    0.5  0.5
6 2015-09-30   2    0.5  0.5
7 2015-12-31   2    2.0  0.5
```

Thanks, tingis

Comment: first element? if you just want to operate on element 0 you don't actually need any special pandas functions. just `df.ix[0]['Value'] > df.ix[0]['Old']` I am getting the feeling your question does not explain your whole case.

Comment: Ah, I think I forgot to mention it in the actual question and just in the title - I need to do this for each group

Comment: `Id`, added it in the question. Sorry for the unclear question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only want to change the first element of each group, you can do a customized groupby apply function to do this.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# your data
# =================================================
table = [[datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 31), 1, 0.5, 1],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 30), 1, 0.5, 0.5],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 30), 1, 0.5, 0.5],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 31), 1, 2, 0.5],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 3, 31), 2, 0.5, 1.5],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 6, 30), 2, 0.5, 0.5],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 9, 30), 2, 0.5, 0.5],
         [datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 31), 2, 2, 0.5]]

df = pd.DataFrame(table, columns=['Date', 'Id', 'Value', 'Old'])

print(df)


        Date  Id  Value  Old
0 2015-03-31   1    0.5  1.0
1 2015-06-30   1    0.5  0.5
2 2015-09-30   1    0.5  0.5
3 2015-12-31   1    2.0  0.5
4 2015-03-31   2    0.5  1.5
5 2015-06-30   2    0.5  0.5
6 2015-09-30   2    0.5  0.5
7 2015-12-31   2    2.0  0.5

# processing
# ====================================
def func(group):
    if group.Value.values[0] < group.Old.values[0]:
        group.Value.values[0] = group.Old.values[0]
    return group

df.groupby('Id').apply(func)

        Date  Id  Value  Old
0 2015-03-31   1    1.0  1.0
1 2015-06-30   1    0.5  0.5
2 2015-09-30   1    0.5  0.5
3 2015-12-31   1    2.0  0.5
4 2015-03-31   2    1.5  1.5
5 2015-06-30   2    0.5  0.5
6 2015-09-30   2    0.5  0.5
7 2015-12-31   2    2.0  0.5
```

Comment: How did you figure out to group by `id`? That is not written in the question anywhere

Comment: Thanks again @Jianxun, I was hoping you'd be online today!

Comment: @firelynx only two values change in the post, and both are in position of the first value for each `Id` cluster. Also, Tingiskhan has posted a few questions regarding this sample dataframe, so I am quite familiar with the structure.